# Put * in front of certain lines using sed

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I have a file with different lines; I am trying to put a `*` in front of lines that contain the key word 'VDD'.  I know I can use `sed` to insert `*` to the beginning of a line, `sed 's/^/*/'`, but I have more than one lines that have the word VDD.  How do I find those lines first then insert using `sed`?

example file:

```
VDD 123 123
123 VDD 123
VSS 22 22 
VDD 123 123
```

Basically I want the above file to become this

```
*VDD 123 123
*123 VDD 123
VSS 22 22 
*VDD 123 123
```

Answer (score 4):

Try doing this :

```
sed '/VDD/s/^/*/' file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '$0=/VDD/?"*"$0:$0'
```

- if line contains `VDD`, prepend `*`
- else just print line as is

Comment: Note the curious side effect that this deletes blank lines from the file, and also lines that only contain zeros.  That's because such lines evaluate to 'false', and hence aren't selected for printing.

Comment: It also delete lines starting with some like this  `0e5`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
awk '/VDD/ {$0="*"$0}1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also work

```
sed '/VDD/s/^./*&/' my_file
```

find all lines with `VDD`. take the first character in these lines and add `*` in behind it